# window.opener with a custom function does not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, window.open, window.opener

I am having an issue with Safari, specifically, not finding the window.opener function from the parent window. The function I'm calling works fine in Chrome and Firefox. Does anyone have any tips?

**Window 1 (Parent)**

Opens window 2 with the following:

```
window.open(requestUrl, "_blank", "width=440, height=500, scrollbars");
```

**Window 2 (Popup)**

After the request url page returns back, the following gets called:

```
window.parent.opener.callBackIntegrationCompleted("testing");
window.close();
```

I get the following error on the first line:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'window.parent.opener.callBackIntegrationCompleted("testing")')
```

Note: I've tried a few variations of window.opener, parent.window.opener, and window.parent.opener.

**Window 1 (Parent) Callback**

The original parent window that opened the popup has the following JS function, but it never gets to this point.

```
function callBackIntegrationCompleted(code) {
    console.log("got here");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: please treat this as comment.

```
function callBackIntegrationCompleted(code) {
    console.log("got here");
}
window.callBackIntegrationCompleted = callBackIntegrationCompleted;
```

inside a call to eval() makes a function in the argument string a property of the window. If the call back function *is defined using eval()* it could be a problem

Comment: awesome! window.callBackIntegrationCompleted = callBackIntegrationCompleted; was exactly what I needed.